# Macro de Excel copiar y pegar celdas con condiciones

Tags: excel, macros, vb, visual, basic

Estoy intentando hacer una macro con Excel y no consigo el resultado que quiero. Abajo os adjunto la tabla que estoy intentando leer y el código desde el que parto.

Lo que quiero es que: Si la primera fila es "OUT" , que busque la siguiente "IN" pero con las condiciones que le digo en el código.

Esto solo me lo está haciendo comparando dos filas consecutivos. Como hago para recorrer la lista y que no importe que el OUT esté en la fila 3 y el IN en la fila 15? (Por ejemplo). Es decir que hasta que no encuentre el IN, no pase a la siguiente fila de OUT. Adjunto el código también:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

 For i = 2 To 100
    If Cells(i, "C").Value = "OUT" Then

      If Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = "IN" And (Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i + 1, "D").Value Or Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i + 1, "E").Value And (Cells(i, "E").Value = Cells(i + 1, "D").Value Or Cells(i, "E").Value = Cells(i + 1, "E").Value) And Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i + 1, "F").Value) And (Cells(i, "G").Value = Cells(i + 1, "G").Value) Then

        'Copiamos a la derecha de la fila correspondiente en base a la comprobación anterior para emparejar'
        Range(Cells(i + 1, "A"), Cells(i + 1, "G")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, "i")
        'Range(Cells(i + 1, "A"), Cells(i + 1, "G")).Value = ""'
      End If
    End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Gracias de antemano!

Jabixo.

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos problemas. El que tu indicas, que se puede resolver con otro bucle `For-Next` y el de la lógica de la evaluación del segundo `If` puesto que mezclas `AND` y `OR` y no creo que el resultado sea el que buscas.

Para resolverlo he puesto un segundo bucle (j), que busca las filas siguientes hasta que encuentra un resultado, luego vuelve al bucle principal (mediante un `Exit for`).
En el segundo `If` fíjate que he puesto paréntesis adicionales para rodear los `OR` de manera que las condiciones se evalúen correctamente.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

 For i = 2 To 100
    If Cells(i, "C").Value = "OUT" Then
       For j=i to 100
          If Cells(j + 1, "C").Value = "IN" 
          And ((Cells(j, "D").Value = Cells(j + 1, "D").Value Or Cells(j, "D").Value = Cells(j + 1, "E").Value( 
          And ((Cells(j, "E").Value = Cells(j + 1, "D").Value Or Cells(j, "E").Value = Cells(j + 1, "E").Value)) 
          And Cells(j, "F").Value = Cells(j + 1, "F").Value) 
          And (Cells(j, "G").Value = Cells(j + 1, "G").Value) Then

        'Copiamos a la derecha de la fila correspondiente en base a la comprobación anterior para emparejar'
        Range(Cells(j + 1, "A"), Cells(j + 1, "G")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(j, "i")
        Exit for
      End If
    Next
End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Lo he hecho al vuelo, sin comprobarlo, pero seguro que si hay algún error lo puedes ajustar a tu necesidad teniendo una idea de como resolverlo.